# When can you factor out terms from a double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Consider the following double integral:

$$ \int \int_{S} (x+z) dS$$

Over the region in first octant of plane $ x+y+z=1$

I know the bounds are :

$$ 0 \leq x \leq 1$$
$$ 0 \leq y \leq 1$$
$$ 0 \leq z \leq 1$$

To start, I first rewrite this integral as:

$$ \int \int_{S} (1-y) \sqrt{3} dx dy$$

And,

$$ \sqrt{3} \int \int_S (1-y) dx dy$$

**Now here is the part I get confused:**

I asked some people and they told I have to do integral with 'y' first (outer integral) and then do the inner integral. This is due to the fact that limits of integral on 'y' depend on 'x'. But, I had this alternative scheme in mind:

Suppose we take the imiplict expression of $ x+y+z=1$ and rewrite it as $ x+z=1-y$ So, suppose we fixed $ 1-y = C$ then we could just vary 'x' and 'z' whilst we integrated and hence factor out the expression from integral.

This gives me:

$$ \sqrt{3} \int (1-y) x dy$$

Similar arguments to keep 'x' constant while I integrate with 'y',

$$ \sqrt{3} x \frac{(1-y)^2}{2}$$

Plugging in the bounds:

$$ 0$$

But, I'm not sure where exactly I went wrong...

Comment: The syntax $g(y)$ seems to indicate that $g$ is a function in $y$ only.  That means that for a specific value of $y, \,g(y)$ is constant as $x$ varies.  Therefore, in the *inner* integral, $\int \,f(x)g(y)dx, \;g(y)$ is a constant.

Comment: I have seen some questions (in physics) where I ended up plugging something in terms of 'x' as bound after integrating with y and then got wrong answer coz I switched order of integration

Comment: Interesting comment.  I am not an expert in this.  However, I thought that (in general), you **are** allowed to switch the order of integration (and still get the same answer).  Could you please provide an example?  Alternatively, perhaps someone very knowledgeable in *multivariable real analysis* could weigh in.

Comment: I think that I should re-phrase my original comment.  If, there are separate functions $u$ and $v$ which map $y$ to $x$ [i.e. $x=u(y)$ and/or $x = v(y)],$ and if the *inner* integral has form $\int_{u(y)}^{v(y)} \,f(x)g(y)dx,\;$ then the *inner* integral should resolve to a function of $y.$

Comment: I agree with @user2661923's first comment, under the assumption that you actually can split it up into two integrals. This "splitting" is done by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). As for the switching of the order , assuming you satisfy Fubini, are you talking about examples such as "Integrate over $D=\{(x,y): 0\leq x \leq 1, \sqrt{x}\leq y\leq 1\} $" where you would have either $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\,dydx \ \text{or} \ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}dxdy$$ depending on $x$ or $y$ first?

Comment: oh I see ,so it is like bounds change when  siwtch order? how do I know how to change bounds also what is like the 'intuitive' reason behind htis?

Comment: Anyways, i think the idea you conveyed is worthy of an answer

Comment: Yes the bounds change. The intuitive reason is that you are either moving along the x-axis (the left integral) or along the y-axis (the right integral) for the inner integral and thus you must choose the integrand which acts like a bound for this direction. The integrands are equal (at least where it matters), take a look at desmos with $y=\sqrt(x)$ and $x=y^2$. As for the switching of the bounds, it is not always the same as with this one and a general method is probably non existent. I think @user2661923 should answer your post. I am sadely in a time crunch right now.

Comment: Correction, the left integral above should go from $\sqrt{x}$ to $1$, my bad

Comment: @DDD4C4U At this point, I think that it would be more constructive for you explore a specific double integral problem where you think that you would get different answers if you reverse the order of integration.  Double check that this is still the case, after the discussion that has already occurred for this posting.  Assuming that you have such an example:  ... to next comment:

Comment: @DDD4C4U Add an addendum to your original query, where you provide the problem, and show your work.  That is, show the specific details where you work the problem **both ways** (i.e. one way where the inner integral involves dx and the other way where you reverse the order of the integration).  Then, add a comment where you **flag me** (i.e. @user2661923) indicating that you have updated your query.  Then I (or a multivariable real analysis expert) can critique the specific work shown in your posting's addendum.

Comment: check now ! @user2661923 pls

Comment: @DDD4C4U I'm not stonewalling; the problem that you added to your original posting goes well beyond my expertise.  My intention was for you to present a problem formatted like $\int_a^b \,\left[\int_c^d \,f(x,y) \,dx\right] \,dy,\;$ and then to re-format the problem as $\int_r^s \,\left[\int_t^u \,g(x,y) \,dy\right] \,dx.$  I then intended that you demonstrate that the two problems yielded two different results.  I then intended to look for and correct a mistake in your work, and show that the corrected work causes the two problems to yield the same answer.  That is the limit of my expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with

$$I= \iint_S (1-y) dS =\sqrt{3} \iint_{x>0,y>0,x+y<1}(1-y) dx dy\\
= \sqrt3 \int_0^1\int_0^{1-y} (1-y)dxdy = \sqrt3\int_0^1 (1-y)^2dy
= \frac1{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: how did you know 'x' is from 0 to 1-y

Comment: @Buraian - Because of the boundary $x+y=1$

Comment: where did you get that condition?

Comment: @Buraianp - it is from the given surface $x+y+z=1$ with $z=0$, i.e. Its $xy$-plane intersection

Answer (score 1):

In order to start talking about breaking out a factor we must make sure that the double integral over a $2$-dimensional region $D$:
$$\iint_{D} f(x,y) \, dA,$$
can be represented as a double *iterated* integral (so we can consider the integrals seperatley):
$$\int_{X}\left(\int_{Y}f(x,y) \, dx \right)dy \ \text{or} \int_{Y}\left(\int_{X}f(x,y) \, dy \right)dx. $$
This can be guranteed (and both integrals are equal) if you can show it to satisfy [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) (altough this is not always easy as you might have to compute both integrals).

Suppose for the sake of argument that Fubini's theorem is satisfied in the following example;

Consider $D = \{(x,y): a \leq y \leq b, \alpha(y)\leq x \leq \beta(y)\}$ to be the area we are going to integrate your function $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ over. Assuming this, we can by Fubini's theorem write
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{\alpha(y)}^{\beta(y)}h(x,y) \,dx\right)dy.$$
Now fix any $y=s\in (a,b)$, then the inner integral is
$$\int_{\alpha(s)}^{\beta(s)}h(x,s)\,dx = \int_{\alpha(s)}^{\beta(s)}f(x)g(s)\,dx =g(s)\int_{\alpha(s)}^{\beta(s)}f(x)\,dx. $$
which can intuitively be seen by noting that we are integrating over a horizontal strip in the $x,y$-plane. By definition, a horizontal line in the $x,y$-plane is parallel to the $x$-axis and lines parallel to the $x$-axis can be described by $y=k\in\mathbb{R}$. So naturally $g(y)$ is constant along any such strip as it dependes only on $y$. So we can say in general that it holds for all of the interval $(a,b)$.

We can therefore write
\begin{align*}\int_{a}^{b} \left( \int_{ \alpha(y)} ^ { \beta(y)} h(x,y) \, dx \right) dy 
&= \int_{a}^{b} \left( \int_{ \alpha(y)}^{ \beta(y)} f(x)g(y) \, dx \right)dy\\
&= \int_{a}^{b} g(y) \left(\int_{ \alpha(y)}^{ \beta(y)} f(x) \, dx \right)dy.\end{align*}
If you want to break out $f(x)$ then you must find a way to change $D$ into something like $D'=\{(x,y):a'\leq x\leq b', \alpha'(x)\leq y \leq \beta'(x)\}$ which still represents the same area. Then by Fubini's theorem
$$\int_{a}^{b} \left( \int_{ \alpha(y)}^{ \beta(y)} f(x)g(y) \, dx \right)dy = \int_{a'}^{b'} \left( \int_{ \alpha'(y)}^{ \beta'(y)} f(x)g(y) \, dy \right)dx$$
but now the inner integral can be considered to be an integration over a vertical strip so $x$ is instead constant along such a strip.

Comment: In stating Fubini's theorem, you used the same integral twice.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! I have corrected it.